# get selected value from selectmenu on form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get the selected value of the selectmenu on form submit.

```
  $('#submitbutton').click(function(){
var returnValue = true;
$('#form1 .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
inputVal = $(".dd-default option:selected").val();
alert(inputVal); -- displaying null
var input = $(this);
alert(input.val()); -- displaying null
if (!input.val()) {
   returnValue = false;
}

});
});
```

Here $(this).val() is displaying null. But when I write the same function on chnage of the selectmenu, its displaying the selected value.

```
$('#form1 .required').change(function () {
var input = $(this);
input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
input.removeClass('required');
alert(input.val());-- displays the value
if (!input.val()) {
    alert("error");
}
});
```

Any idea, why its not displaying the selected value on submit of the form?
Thanks

Comment: Have you verified whether you are able to get object  by this $(".dd-default")

Comment: Hi Mahesh..I didnt get wat u r trying to say..

Comment: IN the first approach you mentioned you are getting null.I am asking whether you got the object or not.

Comment: u mean trying alert($('.dd-default')) ?

Comment: yeah you can try alert id property alert($('.dd-default').attr('id'))or place a debug point check the object properties.

Comment: @MaheshMajeti..I tried alert($('.dd-default').attr('id')).. It is giving some random button number like _button_410 and $(this) is giving Object[a#user_name_button_166.ui-selectmenu #].. This user_name is the id of the dropdown I am using..What does this mean??

Comment: IN your each loop there are some other fileds which satisfying your condition.Can you share the html code.It will be helpful..to find where you are going wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41175/discussion-between-user1049057-and-maheshmajeti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution has resolved above problem.

```
$('select').each(function() {
                    var objName = $(this).attr('name');
                    if ($("select[name=" + objName + "]").css('display').indexOf("none") != -1) {
                        alert($("select[name=" + objName + "] option:selected").val());
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the change after the user switches values . This code should run before you get the value.

```
$('.selectList').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

> Replace .selectList with the Class Name of your select list box.

Comment: Hi Jayanth..I dont want to use id's.. I am trying for class based validation since there are lots of dropdowns that needs to be validated on submit of the form..

Comment: Hi Jayanth..My code works for change function. On change, the value is getting alerted correctly. But when the user submits the form, the value is displayed as null..SO any idea, why on submit the value becomes null?

Comment: Make sure the submit event is triggered after the change function is implemented .

Comment: Yes change is before submit function

Comment: or try nesting the calls , run change , within that function at the end , try submitting the form .

Comment: But I need to check for so many other conditions and then only submit the form.. So any way of doing that?

Comment: Do this at the last after all conditions you have checked .